# Ajax show modal not firing from the first click

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, bootstrap-modal

My show modal in ajax won't work on the first click, it appends on the first click but the show modal only triggers after the 2nd click

```
        $("a#get-support-ticket-form").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/support-ticket',
            success: function(data) {
                $("#support-ticket-modal").append(data); // Append the data
                $("#suppor-ticket").modal('show');
            },
            error: function(error) {
                console.log("error")
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: From your jQuery selector `a#get-support-ticket-form` I suspect that you are clicking on an Html <a> tag. Is this right? If so try change your click listener to `.click(function( event )` and call `event.preventDefault()` before the ajax call. Maybe this will help.

Comment: Hello @JonasWeinhardt, I've tried it but it is the same results. Keep in mind the append code gets executed from the first click, so when I click again it gets appended twice and the modal shows

Comment: Hm ok. What version of bootstrap are you using? I will try to setup a codepen that will replicate your problem so it would be nice to know the version of bootstrap that you are using.

Comment: @JonasWeinhardt, I'm using Bootstrap v3.3.7. Do you think is it because the show modal function is trigger with the append at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the way to do it but, I added 'async:false' and it works now.

```
  $("a#get-support-ticket-form").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/support-ticket',
        success: function(data) {
            $("#support-ticket-modal").append(data); // Append the data
            $("#suppor-ticket").modal('show');
        },
        error: function(error) {
            console.log("error")
        }
    });
});
```